# binary < ascii > hex convert

Tags: c#, binary, hex, ascii, converters

Ok so I have the following code that I looked up on the internet but for my project I am not allowed to use code and just throw it in if it works. I have to understand it and be able to give and explanation on the code and what it's doing.

```
Convert.ToInt32("a").ToString("x");//ascii to hex
String.Join(String.Empty, 
      stringInput.Select(
         c => Convert.ToString(
            Convert.ToUInt32(c.ToString(), 16), 2).PadLeft(4, '0')));
```

Can you give me an explanation of these two lines please?

Comment: So what **exactly** you have trouble understanding in this line?

Comment: Perhaps you should write it one step at a time and single-step in the debugger. For example, `int i = Convert.ToInt32("a");`. Then see what the value of `i` is. Then `string s = i.ToString("x");` and inspect the value of `s`. That will give you an understanding of what those things do. Or, you could look up the documentation for those methods.

Comment: @JimMischel I understand that i.toString("x"); formats the text but how does it make "a" into hex without specifying its in base 16?

Comment: `"a"` is already a string of hex digits, you can't "make it" into hex. You can convert the string of hex digits `"a"` into the corresponding integer `0x0a` by using `ToInt32("a", 16)`, but if you turn around and convert that back to a string, using the hex format specifier, you just get `"a"` back again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code looks complex, because the author tried to pack as much functionality into one line as possible. (Were I in a grouchier mood I'd call this "showing off" and would probably complain if a junior tried to check this in.) However, no single part of that line of code is complex; just break it apart piece by piece and examine each bit.

For starters, that first line is just rubbish; `ToInt32("a")` throws a `FormatException` because you didn't specify the base of 16, as: `ToInt32("a", 16)`. If you fix it, though, it's going to return `10.ToString("x")` which is `"a"`. So ignore that line, it does nothing useful. (We can imagine the author meant to use something like `Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes()` to return `0x61`, but they did not.)

The second line, you break down each bit and see what it does:

```
String.Join(String.Empty,
```

This is pretty easy: it's going to take an array of strings and [join them together](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0.aspx), using `String.Empty` as the separator (IOW, no separation.)

```
  stringInput.Select(
```

Here's we're using LINQ to build up an `IEnumerable` of strings; it's going to loop through the characters in the string, one at a time, and execute the lambda expression on each one.

```
     c => Convert.ToString(
        Convert.ToUInt32(c.ToString(), 16), 2).PadLeft(4, '0')));
```

Here's where it gets messy, because even for me matching up those parenthesis by eye is a pain, but if you expand the nested function calls into temporaries, you get:

```
s = c.ToString();              // Convert the character to a string
u = Convert.ToUInt32(s, 16);   // Convert a string of hex digits to a uint
b = Convert.ToString(u, 2);    // Convert a uint to a string of binary digits.
return b.PadLeft(4, '0')));    // Add 0s to make the string at least 4 digits.
```

Each one of those "returned" values becomes the next element in the enumerable, which is returned by `Select`, which is then joined.

The end result here is that you start with a string of hexadecimal digits from 0 - F which, when read as a number, has some particular numeric value, and you end up with a string of binary digits 0 and 1 which, when read as a number, has the same numeric value. IOW, you are "converting" a string of hex digits into an "equivalet" string of binary digits.

Comment: Ok I understand it a lot better now that it has been split up into bite size chunks, but is there an equivalent for my first line that doesn't guess? Also thanks for this in-depth explanation.

Comment: I'm not sure what the point of the first line is to begin with; if you used `Convert.ToInt32("a", 16).ToString("x");` then it would "run" but it still wouldn't do anything useful. (That's also ignoring the fact that you aren't even storing the result anywhere.)

Comment: oh it is storing the value in a string array I just didn't show that because I know how to append ect to a string. Basically its meant to convert a string to hex.

Comment: That's what I figured, but it's not doing that. That's not what `ToInt32()` does. That line of code throws an exception. Also, you need to be really careful about saying things like "convert a string to hex" as that makes no technical sense, and if you aren't *very* clear about what you want to accomplish you'll end up accomplishing the wrong thing.